# git: where cloned remote repository is saved?

Tags: git

I cloned using the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/atinesh-s/Chat-Application
```

Now I want to know where is downloaded in order to unzip it.

Comment: Should be in your working directory. What git client did you use?

Comment: _"in order to unzip it"_ - there's no unzipping involved, why would you think so? Anyway, after cloning, you need to checkout a branch.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to take a copy of a git repository, you can often do a few things, depending on the host. Using the methods supported by git alone, you have an option to create a new, empty, repository, or else you clone an existing repository into the specified directory (or existing directory, as your command does). See the [Pro Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository) for starters.

```
git clone https://github.com/atinesh-s/Chat-Application
```

Will clone into the current directory, no zip file used.

```
git clone https://github.com/atinesh-s/Chat-Application <dir1>
```

Will clone into the specified directory dir1.

There are a bunch of great online resources covering this stuff, go have a Google.